# Verilog sequential logic test bench

Tags: verilog

I am trying to write a test bench for a sequential multiplier using add and shift.
However, I am running into problems as my input and output waveform are misaligned by 20ns. My inputs receives signal at t = 0ns but my output doesn't have a signal until t = 20ns. (output from t = 0 to t = 20 are all XX). Ignoring the 20ns delay visually, my results are correct. However, because the input output waveform are misaligned for 20ns, the tcl console tells me it is incorrect. Below is my code:

```
module multiplier_testbench;
reg[3:0]x,y;
wire [7:0] product;
integer i,j; //loop counter
integer k = 0;
reg clock, reset, enable;  

multi mul(clock, reset, enable, a,b, result); //Instantiate multiplier module

initial
    begin

       clock = 0;
       reset = 0;
       enable = 0;

       for(i = 0; i < 16; i = i + 1) 
       begin
           for(j = 0; j < 16; j = j + 1) 
           begin
               clock = 1;
               enable = 1;

               assign a = i;
               assign b = j;

              #5;
               clock = 0;
               enable = 0;
               #5;

               if(result !== {a} * {b})//comparing result using * operator in verilog
               begin
                $display("Wrong");
                    k = k + 1;
                end
           end
       end 
       if (k == 0) $display("success");
       else $display("%d Error(s)", k);
   end 
   endmodule
```

Below is the waveform generated by the test bench:
[image]

I have tried to delay the inputs by 20ns but that just adds additional 20ns to the outputs. I believe the problem comes from my clock but I have had no success at placing it elsewhere. I know I am really close to get it but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you used a very *advanced* verilog feature `procedural assignments` inside the `initial` block, in particular assigning ports to registers. Are you sure that you really wanted to use  `assign a =i` and `assign b = j` there?

Comment: Where is `a`, `b`, and `result` defined? As is they are all inferred one bit wires. Perhaps you should intended to connect them to `x`, `y`, and `product`?

Comment: Thanks for the advice and suggestions. I have figured out what is wrong with my test bench. It turns out I am missing a submodule inside the     multi module.

Answer (score 0):

The delay is likely coming from the submodule `multi`. Share it so that we can help.

Comment: this is not an answer, just a comment.

Comment: @Serge i must have 50 reputations to comment, i have 38